# Appropriate object creation - finding universal solution

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

There are 3 classes (there may be much more), which have the same procedure (procedure Populate). They are nearly identical and differs only by object creation. All I want is to write a universal procedure in the base class, which will replace this notorious repeating of code forever. I am not really sure, if I can express exactly what I am up to, but look at the code below and see.

```
  TGrandFather = class(TObject)

  end;

  TFather = class(TGrandFather)

  end;

  TSon = class(TFather)

  end;

  TGrandson.... and so on... 



  TGrandFathers = class (TList)
  public
    procedure Populate(Amount:Integer);
  end;

  TFathers = class (TGrandFathers)
  public
    procedure Populate(Amount:Integer);
  end;

  TSons = class (TFathers)
  public
    procedure Populate(Amount:Integer);
  end;

  TGrandsons.... 
...

procedure TGrandFathers.Populate(Amount:Integer);
var i:integer;
    xGrandFather:TGrandFather;
begin
   for i := 0 to Amount do
   begin
   xGrandFather:=TGrandFather.Create;
   Add(xGrandFather);
   end;
end;

procedure TFathers.Populate(Amount:Integer);
var i:integer;
    xFather:TFather;
begin
   for i := 0 to Amount do
   begin
   xFather:=TFather.Create;    //this is the point, which makes trouble
   Add(xFather);
   end;
end;

procedure TSons.Populate(Amount:Integer);
var i:integer;
    xSon:TSon;
begin
   for i := 0 to Amount do
   begin
   xSon:=TSon.Create;          //this is the point, which makes trouble
   Add(xSon);
   end;
end;

procedure Grandsons...
```

Thanx...

Comment: Use generic containers

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : I think   generic containers are introduced from Delphi 2009. Unfortunately I use Delphi 7

Comment: The question is tagged delphi. You did not mention a version.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I added the Delphi 7 tag now based on the comment. OP, the version of Delphi is really important with this sort of question as there are language features that are being added all of the time. There is no way for us to guess which version of Delphi you are using and which features we can make use of.

Comment: Also, your inheritance is massively borked. I am a father. I am not a grandfather. My son is neither father nor grandfather.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : I wanted to underpin the lineage of ancestors... So there is no other way to circumvent this matter in D7?

Comment: It's the wrong way round though. Not all sons are fathers.

Comment: @David, but sons are *descendants* of fathers, just as `TSon` is a descendant of `TFather`.

Comment: @Rob Bad analogy. Try `Assert(son is TGrandfather)`.

Comment: Sons are descendants of grandfathers, too, @David. That's what the `is` operator checks. "Bad analogy"? It's common OOP terminology, along with "parent class" and "child class." I didn't make up the analogy.

Comment: @Rob That's not what `is` checks in my opinion. It might not be your analogy, but the fact that it's not yours doesn't make it right. A grandfather is a father, but a father is not necessarily a grandfather. We can all agree on that.

Comment: I agree that behavior of the `is` operator can be described in other ways, @David, but literally its implementation calls `InheritsFrom`, which checks the trail of *parent* classes. That illustrates my point, which is that the terminology of descendant classes is pervasive, and so there was no need to criticize this person for presenting a set of classes named according to that terminology.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your question, you could use a metaclass through "class of" if you want to go the route you are going. This block of code demonstrates how you would accomplish that. The hierarchy needs to be cleaned up but you should get the gist of what is going on through this code.

A metaclass is a class whose instances are classes. This allows you to build a more generic framework because you can then use your metaclass to create the classes that you need.

```
type
  TGrandFather = class(TObject)

  end;

  TStrangeHeirarchyClass = class of TGrandFather;

  TFather = class(TGrandFather)

  end;

  TSon = class(TFather)

  end;

  TGrandFathers = class(TList)
  protected
    procedure PopulateInternal(aAmount:Integer; aContainedClass:
        TStrangeHeirarchyClass);
  public
    procedure Populate(Amount:Integer);
  end;

  TFathers = class (TGrandFathers)
  public
    procedure Populate(Amount:Integer);
  end;

  TSons = class (TFathers)
  public
    procedure Populate(Amount:Integer);
  end;

implementation

procedure TGrandFathers.Populate(Amount:Integer);
begin
  PopulateInternal(Amount, TGrandFather);
end;

procedure TGrandFathers.PopulateInternal(aAmount:Integer; aContainedClass:
    TStrangeHeirarchyClass);
var
  i:integer;
  xFamilyMember:TGrandFather;
begin
  for i := 0 to aAmount do
  begin
    xFamilyMember := aContainedClass.Create;
    Add(xFamilyMember);
  end;
end;

procedure TFathers.Populate(Amount:Integer);
begin
  PopulateInternal(Amount, TFather);
end;

procedure TSons.Populate(Amount:Integer);
begin
  PopulateInternal(Amount, TSon);
end;
```

The way it works is that the metaclass `TStrangeHeirarchyClass`, which you can use just like a regular data type, stores the underlying class that you would like to work with. You can pass the type in as a parameter (like I did in the code example above) or store it in the class as a property or field like this:

```
  TGrandFathers = class(TList)
  private
    FContainedClass: TStrangeHeirarchyClass;
  public
    procedure Populate(Amount:Integer);
    property ContainedClass: TStrangeHeirarchyClass read 
        FContainedClass write FContainedClass;
  end;
```

Once you have set this property you would then be able to use it to create instances of the class type that it was set to. So, setting the `ContainedClass` as a `TFather` would result in calls to `ContainedClass.Create` creating instances of `TFather`.

As David indicated in the comments, you will run into problems if you use a metaclass and override the default constructor. Your code in the constructor will never run. You either need to wither use virtual constructors or override the existing `AfterConstruction` method which is a virtual method that is called by the constructor. Something like this would be an example if you were using `AfterConstruction`:

```
  TGrandFathers = class(TList)
  protected
    FContainedClass: TStrangeHeirarchyClass;
  public
    procedure AfterConstruction; override;
    procedure Populate(Amount:Integer);
  end;

  TFathers = class (TGrandFathers)
  public
    procedure AfterConstruction; override;
  end;

  TSons = class (TFathers)
  public
    procedure AfterConstruction; override;
  end;

implementation

procedure TGrandFathers.AfterConstruction;
begin
  inherited;
  FContainedClass := TGrandFather;
  // Other construction code
end;

procedure TGrandFathers.Populate(aAmount:Integer);
var
  i:integer;
  xFamilyMember:TGrandFather;
begin
  for i := 0 to aAmount do
  begin
    xFamilyMember := FContainedClass.Create;
    Add(xFamilyMember);
  end;
end;

procedure TFathers.AfterConstruction;
begin
  inherited;
  FContainedClass := TFather;
  // Other construction code
end;

procedure TSons.AfterConstruction;
begin
  inherited;
  FContainedClass := TSon;
  // Other construction code
end;
```

Your hierarchy looks very strange though. I think something like this would be more appropriate:

```
type
  TRelationType = (ptSon, ptFather, ptGrandfather);

  TPerson = class;

  TRelation = class(TObject)
  strict private
    FRelationship: TRelationType;
    FRelation: TPerson;
  public
    property Relation: TPerson read FRelation write FRelation;
    property Relationship: TRelationType read FRelationship write FRelationship;
  end;

  TRelationList = class(TList)
    //...
  end;

  TPerson = class(TObject)
  strict private
    FPersonName: string;
    FRelations: TRelationList;
  public
    procedure AfterConstruction; override;
    procedure BeforeDestruction; override;
    property PersonName: string read FPersonName write FPersonName;
    property Relations: TRelationList read FRelations;
  end;

implementation

procedure TPerson.AfterConstruction;
begin
  inherited;
  FRelations := TRelationList.Create;
end;

procedure TPerson.BeforeDestruction;
begin
  FRelations.Free;
  inherited;
end;
```

Comment: Yes, this is what helped me a lot... I did not know how to parametrize class... Thanx... :-) The true hierarchy I use in original code is somewhat different, thats why your suggestion is good, but only for this case...

Comment: I have to admit, my choice of the class names is confusing... I hoped it makes things clear, but it seems, it did otherwise. Your first answer did the job, really...

Comment: @lyborko I thought your question was probably one constructed to demonstrate a  specific problem you were encountering but had to cover the base in case it wasn't :)

Comment: Virtual constructors are essential with metaclasses. No constructors defined here, but as soon as the asker maps to the real code then this issue is likely to arise.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks, I initially used AfterConstruction and BeforeDestruction instead of the template pattern. Would be a good idea to add that to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
//MMWIN:CLASSCOPY
unit _MM_Copy_Buffer_;

interface


implementation

type
  TBaseSelfCreating = class(TObject)
    procedure Populate(Amount: Integer);
    procedure Add(Obj: TObject);
  end;


{TBaseSelfCreating}

procedure TBaseSelfCreating.Add(Obj: TObject);
begin
  Assert(Obj is TBaseSelfCreating);
  Assert(Obj <> Self);
  Obj.Free;
end;

procedure TBaseSelfCreating.Populate(Amount: Integer);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to Amount do Add(Self.ClassType.Create);
end;

end.
```

Comment: @ MartynA
I believe it solves this requirement: All I want is to write a universal procedure in the base class, which will replace this notorious repeating of code forever

Comment: This is a demo for Populate not Add, The question did not supply a add function so it could be anything and it doesn't matter. The question also included "but look at the code below and see" so I looked at the code and saw his comments to back up his question. What happens when Add returns is irrelevant. For me to run this and test all I needed was to create, check the validity of the object and free it. My real question is why am I spending time typing this??

Comment: Populate is supposed to be on the collection class from the way I read the question.

Comment: @ MartynA  That "Voice" did not include FreeAndNil'ing a pointer that won't be accessible after add returns.. Sounds to me like the "Voice" was correct..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You seem to be suggesting the same `Self.ClassType.Create` solution as Abelisto's answer, but you don't actually *say* that. Instead, you present some code and expect the reader to figure out which parts are important. When you do that, you risk readers finding other details in your code and misinterpreting *them* as the important parts, as is seen here where you *free* an object in a method named `Add`. You should just remove the `Add` method; it wasn't provided in the question, and it's not important to the answer.

Comment: @ Rob Kennedy - Thanks, its important to the validity testing. There are two functions, I'll let the reader guess which are important to his Question..

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `Self.ClassType.Create`:

```
program Project13;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

type
  TFoo1 = class
    procedure Boo;
  end;

  TFoo2 = class(TFoo1)
  end;

{ TFoo1 }

procedure TFoo1.Boo;
var
  x: TFoo1;
begin
  x := Self.ClassType.Create as TFoo1;
  write(Cardinal(Self):16, Cardinal(x):16);
  Writeln(x.ClassName:16);
end;

begin
  try
    TFoo1.Create.Boo;
    TFoo2.Create.Boo;
    Readln;
  except
    on E:Exception do
      Writeln(E.Classname, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Self.Create does not create a new instance.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks, it was surprise for me. Fixed.

Comment: Calling `ClassType.Create` works fine as long as none of the classes involved introduce constructors of their own. Those constructors won't get called, although the `as` and `is` operators will continue to behave just the same as before. To call the right constructor, it's sometimes necessary to type-cast `ClassType` to a more specific base class, instead of the default `TClass`.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use **Generics** or you are using a version of Delphi without Generics, then this is a way.  Yes, I know I can use forward declaration to remove one class, but this is clearer to follow.

Interface

```
type
  TBaseAncestor = class
  end;

  TBaseClass = class of TBaseAncestor;

  TGrandFathers = class (TBaseAncestor)
    FClassType : TBaseClass;
    constructor Create (AOwner : TControl); reintroduce; virtual;
    procedure Populate;
    procedure Add (X : TBaseAncestor);
  end;

  TFathers = class (TGrandFathers)
    constructor Create (AOwner : TControl); override;
  end;
```

Implementation

```
{ TGrandFathers }

constructor TGrandFathers.Create(AOwner: TControl);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FClassType := TGrandFathers;
end;

procedure TGrandFathers.Add (X : TBaseAncestor);
begin

end;

procedure TGrandFathers.Populate;
const
  Amount = 5;
var
  I : integer;
  x : TBaseAncestor;
begin
   for I := 0 to Amount do
   begin
     x := FClassType.Create;
     Add (x);
   end;
end;

{ TFathers }

constructor TFathers.Create(AOwner: TControl);
begin
  inherited;
  FClassType := TFathers;
end;
```

Each descendant stores its class into the **class variable**.  And **Populate** uses this for Creation.  I have been using this before Generics came along.